# Visual Studio Code Ignore Invalid color format

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

In my VS Code `settings.json`, I have a few lines for the TODO Tree extension and they want me to use rgb or hex codes but my VS Code highlights me them with this error.

It works but it bothers me to see these "error" lines.

Can somebody tell me how to disable them or how to write it so that they don't show up.

Error:

> Invalid color format. Use #RGB, #RGBA, #RRGGBB or #RRGGBBAA

I haven't really tried anything because I don't know what to use.

Comment: Then why not post to its author(s)? https://github.com/Gruntfuggly/todo-tree/issues

Comment: if you don't show us what you have in your settings.json file, config properties with `"format": "color-hex"` only accept hex colors, rgb colors are not accepted

Comment: @rioV8 thanks I just had to use the hex format and not rgb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: use the hex format and not the rgb.